# Where is the history of Greyhawk deities and dragons written?

Tags: dragons, religions-and-deities, lore, greyhawk

I would like to find and read the lore of gods and dragons of Greyhawk — how they were originally created, how they have changed, and so on.

I searched a bit but I couldn't find anything. What book or books contain background information on the origins of the gods and dragons?

As the comments say, I do not want to know/find out how gods and dragons evolved by the writers but how they evolved in the world of GH. How gods/immortals started, how evolved, how the dragons are connected to gods etc.

I have seen bits of such information (e.g. the "war" against Tharizdun or the creation of Drakes) but on one hand I do not know if they are not home brewed (i.e. because I have seen them in random blogs they could be just a story of the blogger) and on the other what is the greater story and how are connected all together.

Answer (score 5):

**Print(-ish)**

Well, your best bet is to read one of the Greyhawk sourcebooks that covers their deities. The [Living Greyhawk Gazetteer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Greyhawk_Gazetteer) is the most recent, but the [original World of Greyhawk setting boxed set just became available in PDF from dndclassics.com](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/17392/World-of-Greyhawk-Fantasy-Game-Setting-1e?it=1&filters=0_44711_0). The later From The Ashes boxed set, the Greyhawk Adventures hardback, and the Player's Guide to Greyhawk that are also available in PDF there also have deity information in them but it's largely identical information.

The Greyhawk gods have been developed and rehashed a lot over time, especially in Dragon magazine/Polyhedron/Living Greyhawk Journal articles and the like and there may be inconsistencies (especially in 4e-5e once they started mashing the deities up together into a generic "D&D Pantheon").

**Web**

Canonfire is the most respected Oerth Web site, and they have a [wiki of the gods](http://www.canonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=List_of_Greyhawk_deities) with more information that does some sourcing of where specific pieces of information are from. The content there is intended to all be canon and not sourced from fan writeups. There's also a free guide to the GH gods [on the now-hidden Living Greyhawk site](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/welcome).

**Dragons?**

There are some dragon deities, but in Greyhawk there's no such thing as "the gods and dragons" like that's some kind of pantheon; dragons are just big critters on Oerth. In later editions Bahamut and Tiamat got promoted into the "Generic D&D Pantheon" but that's not so in Greyhawk proper. There are major dragons of GH named in various places - like here's a thread that mentions [some Draconomicon references to major GH dragons](http://community.wizards.com/forum/greyhawk/threads/1688946) - but they are not spoken of in the same way as even the least of deities. There's also [a Canonfire list of known dragons](http://www.canonfire.com/cf/modules.php?name=Content&pa=showpage&pid=7) and they're pretty rare.

Comment: I didn't get the impression from the question that they're conflating dragons with gods, just looking for both as "super old things". (Also, much has been written on the origins of standard-colour dragons in other settings, so the origin story of the grey Greyhawk dragons being obviously different raises a question mark.)

Comment: Still rates a different question then. May as well ask about "the development of gods and terrain features."

Comment: I have read in an article that Dragons gave some eggs to the immortals and from that eggs the Drakes were born. That is the reason which lead me to write for both gods and dragons.